# SBT not honouring a custom resolver

Tags: scala, sbt, dependency-management, ivy, artifactory

In my SBT based Scala project, I'm trying to fetch a managed dependency from a artifactory server that my organisation has deployed.

However, when I build my project, sbt doesn't look for the dependency on that server and fails.

I have correctly set the ivy credentials and also verified that the dependency exists at the specified location on artifactory (thorough web interface).

**This is project/plugins.sbt:**

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

resolvers += "my-library" at "https://artifactory.myorg.com/artifactory/libs-release-local"

credentials := (Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / "credentials" ** "*").filter(_.isFile).get.map(Credentials(_))
```

**This is build.sbt:**

```
name := "untitled"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.myorg" %% "my-library" % "1.0.21"
)
```

**Output:**

```
sbt clean compile
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/tsudake/untitled/project
[info] Set current project to untitled (in build file:/Users/tsudake/untitled/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 23 Jan, 2017 4:04:48 PM
[info] Updating {file:/Users/tsudake/untitled/}untitled...
[info] Resolving com.myorg#my-library_2.10;1.0.21 ...
[warn]  module not found: com.myorg#my-library_2.10;1.0.21
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/tsudake/.ivy2/local/com.myorg/my-library_2.10/1.0.21/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/myorg/my-library_2.10/1.0.21/my-library_2.10-1.0.21.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.myorg#my-library_2.10;1.0.21: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.myorg:my-library_2.10:1.0.21 (/Users/tsudake/untitled/build.sbt#L7-11)
[warn]        +- default:untitled_2.10:1.0
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.myorg#my-library_2.10;1.0.21: not found
    at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:291)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:188)
    at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:165)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:132)
    at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
    at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:127)
    at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:124)
    at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:155)
    at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:165)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1369)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1365)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1399)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$87.apply(Defaults.scala:1397)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1402)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1396)
    at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
    at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1419)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1348)
    at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1310)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.myorg#my-library_2.10;1.0.21: not found
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed 23 Jan, 2017 4:04:52 PM
```

As you can see, sbt checks only maven and local repo, completely ignoring artifactory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've added artifactory as the new repository for plugins (in the `plugin.sbt`), but you need it as the repository for dependencies (just add this resolver to `build.sbt`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to move

```
resolvers += "my-library" at "https://artifactory.myorg.com/artifactory/libs-release-local"
```

to build.sbt

so with this your build.sbt should look like this:

```
name := "untitled"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.myorg" %% "my-library" % "1.0.21"
)

resolvers += "my-library" at "https://artifactory.myorg.com/artifactory/libs-release-local"
```

and your plugins.sbt is this:

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

credentials := (Path.userHome / ".ivy2" / "credentials" ** "*").filter(_.isFile).get.map(Credentials(_))
```